# Fill column with info from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get **zipcode** data from a dataframe to fill another dataframe missing *NaN* zipcode values. I'm using the **street name** and the **number** of the address to search the best zipcode match but my functions work only when hardcoding the values.

Here is some dummy data for the first dataframe:

```
sufixo = ['ST', 'ST', 'AV', 'ST', 'AV']
logradouro = ['JEFF', '9TH', 'CRAZY', 'SEXY', 'TEST']
number = [123, 444, 1204, 40, 55]
zipcode = [None, None, None, None, None]

dataset = list(zip(sufixo, logradouro, number, zipcode))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset, columns=['suffix', 's_name', 'number', 'zipcode'])
```

Now the second one:

```
street_name = ['CRAZY AV', 'SEXY ST', '9TH ST', 'JEFF ST', 'TEST AV', 'CRAZY AV', 'SEXY ST', 'TEST AV']
number = [100, 23, 666, 24, 54, 1200, 39, 100]
zipcode = [11122, 11133, 11166, 11100, 11144, 11155, 11199, 11177]

dataset = list(zip(street_name, number, zipcode))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset, columns=['street_name', 'number', 'zipcode'])
```

The function for getting the nearest number:

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).idxmin()
    return array[idx]
```

The function for concatenating the street name:

```
def concat_st_name(row):
    return row['s_name'] + " " + row['suffix']

df['combo_name'] = df.apply(concat_st_name, axis=1)
```

And my failing function that tries to get a decent zipcode:

```
def zip_finder(row):
        return df2['zipcode'][(df2['street_name'] == row['combo_name']) &
                              (df2['number'] == find_nearest(df2[df2['street_name'] == row['combo_name']]['number'], row['number']))]
```

When trying to apply this with `df['ziptest'] = df.apply(zip_finder, axis=1)`

I get a: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1`

If I generate a `ziptest` column with 0's before, I get a new dataframe like this:[image: my failure exposed]

I'm new to Pandas and I think I'm failing to understand the logic of the **apply** method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can just using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
df['street_name']=df['s_name'] + " " + df['suffix']

pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('number').drop('zipcode',1),df2.sort_values('number'),by='street_name',on='number',direction ='nearest')
Out[1176]: 
  suffix s_name  number street_name  zipcode
0     ST   SEXY      40     SEXY ST    11199
1     AV   TEST      55     TEST AV    11144
2     ST   JEFF     123     JEFF ST    11100
3     ST    9TH     444      9TH ST    11166
4     AV  CRAZY    1204    CRAZY AV    11155
```

Comment: Hi Wen, thanks for such an elegant solution. This will work! I overthought it!

Comment: @GabrielMontañola yw : -) happy coding